# Unti Test: Mock a method result

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

```
    public void Pay()
    {
        // some insert db code 
        // ...

        // Call Bank api
        BankApi api = new BankApi();
        int result = api.pay();
        if(result == 1)
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

I dont want to call `api` in unit test. How to mock the pay method without modify inner code (such as the line `new BankApi()` code)?

Comment: When you say `without modify inner code` you mean you can't change that code **at all**? So you couldn't, say, replace `BankApi` with an interface such as `IBankApi`?

Comment: there is no way to do this without rewriting your code in a loosely coupled manner.

Comment: You may be able to do this using TypeMock. It's better to rewrite your code to use DI if you can but if that absolutely isn't an option, TypeMock might be able to help you. Look up solate.Fake.AllInstances<BaseClass>(); It's been a few years since I've used TypeMock.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible to mock your BankApi class without changing any of your legacy code, you just need a unit testing framework that allows you to mock concrete classes.
for example a test for your method with Typemock :

```
[TestMethod]
public void ExampleTest()
{
    //fakes the next BankApi instace 
    var handler = Isolate.Fake.NextInstance<BankApi>();

    //change the pay method behavior
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => handler.pay()).WillReturn(1);

    new ClassUnderTest().Pay();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, as stated, you should create an Interface.

```
public interface IBankApi 
{
    int pay();
}
```

Then, what you can do is mock this interface like this (I'm using Moq "Mock you" here, you will need to add the NuGet package "Moq" as reference to your application, and you could use other mocking libraries of course)

```
apiMock = new Mock<IBankApi>();
```

just after that you will tell what this call should return (that would be actual mocking)

```
apiMock.Setup(x => x.pay()).Returns(1); //
```

Then, this api "pseudo object", can be used by using apiMock.Object

Now , this information I just gave you doesn't directly solve your problem.

---

**As stated in the comments, you need a better uncoupling of your code.**

You need, for example, some kind of "dependency injection" to allow for such a uncoupling.

Here is a simple example of how it can be done :

```
public class ClassThatUsesYourBankApi 
{
    private readonly IBankApi _api;

    // the constructor will be given a reference to the interface
    public ClassThatUsesYourBankApi (IBankApi api)
    {
        // here you could check for null parameter and throw exception as needed
        this._api = api;
    }

    // this method can now be tested with the mock interface 
    public void MethodThatUseTheApi() 
    {
        int result = this._api.pay();

        if (result == 1) 
        {
            // some things that happens   
        }
        else
        {
            // some other thing
        }
    }
}
```

How to unit test that method :

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

[TestClass]
public class TestMyMethod 
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyMethod_WithBankApiReturns1_ShouldHaveThingsThatHappens()
    {
        // Arrange
        var apiMock = new Mock<IBankApi>();
        apiMock.Setup(api => api.pay())
            .Returns(1);

        var myObject = new ClassThatUsesYourBankApi(apiMock.Object);

        // Act
        int result = myObject.MethodThatUseTheApi();

        // Assert
        // Here you test that the things that should have happened when the api returns 1 actually have happened.
    }
}
```

---

**The key thing to understand here, is that you must not instantiate the api you need to mock in the method you want to test**

In other words, "uncoupling" your method with your api is done by programming to an interface, and code such as you don't have 
`var api = new BankApi()`
directly in the method you want to unit test.

I showed a way to do that, and there are other.